# After calling two API call and update two state, only the first state was updated as expected after rendering, why is that?

Tags: reactjs

In my react project,

I have two states, one is Projection, other is called StressProjections

I have a function that will invoke two Api call, once the api return come back. It will update both state

Below is my code.

```
 //call Api 1 
    axios
      .post<IProjectionResponse>(`/api1`, normalProjectionRequest)
      .then(res => {
        const result = res.data.result
        props.setProjection(result)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })

    //call Api 2
    axios
      .post<IStressProjectionResponse>(
        `api2`,
        stressProjectionRequest
      )
      .then(res => {
        const result = res.data.result
        props.setStressProjections(result)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
```

However, I notice that my StressProjections is always set with "" , empty value. But I am sure the api 2 call is valid, and the return does have something in it. But after rendering, only state Projection have response data in it, but no data in state StressProjections

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox example?

Comment: Could it be possible that one request is faster and changing the state rerenders the component, thus the second request can't finish?

Comment: @AliWahab its just within a function called handleSubmit. I dont have sandbox for this

Comment: @niklasbec if there is some way to check it or force it to finish ?

Comment: @AeLeung I will write you an answer.

Comment: @niklasbec thanks,  while debugging for this, I also have a doubt that if the const result blinded to same data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my suspicion is that you update a piece of state and rerender the component before the other request is done, but it is hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code.

**Try this and see if it solves your issue (post more code if not):**

```
const promise1 = axios.post<IProjectionResponse>(`/api1`, normalProjectionRequest)

const promise2 = axios.post<IStressProjectionResponse>(`api2`,stressProjectionRequest)

Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
.then(values => {
  props.setProjection(**VAL HERE**)
  props.setStressProjections(**VAL HERE**)
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

For the future, it is generally better practice to package multiple requests in a Promise all, this way you have to write way less code for error handling etc.

**If you need to know which promise failed:**

```
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  axios
    .get("https://api.github.com/users/niklasbec")
    .then((data) => {
      resolve(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  axios
    .get("https://api.github.com/users/noneexistinguser123")
    .then((data) => {
      resolve(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
});

Promise.allSettled([promise1, promise2]).then((vals) => {
  console.log(vals);
  vals.forEach((val, index) => {
     if(val.status === "rejected") {
       if(index === 0) {
         //ERROR handling 1
         console.log("error in promise 1")
       } else {
         //ERROR handling 2
         console.log("error in promise 2")
       }
     }
  })
});
```

This will let you do whatever you want with the error handling, hope that helps.

**BTW: If you are wondering why I am wrapping the axios promise in another promise, I have to resolve manually so I can pass the response value of the request, maybe axios has a native way to do it but I don't know of one. Anyway, it works.**

Comment: Thanks, may I know if it is possible to keep my different catch error handling ; right now, there only allowed one error handling and we dont know which promise is dead

Comment: Coz it seems it is all or nothing.... I also want the result could be acceptable when there is only one returning. For example, when api 2 is fail.... I could do setStressProjections(mock data when it is failed). In that way, I could make sure I will still have sth to show.  Same goes for Api 1 when it goes failed

Comment: You can make use of promise.allsettled, I will explain it above.

Comment: @AeLeung I updated it for you, please check if it helps you!

Comment: would re-render run before Promise.allSettled finish?

Comment: Not if you set the state below the vals.forEach all the way at the end.

Comment: Thanks .... btw, just wonder why dont you use await? like First await in the first call , then secondly, call the scond api use wait aswell

Comment: I just tried the code too, May I know how do you get back the data(response) from api for setting the state? as value only has status and reason key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247295/discussion-between-niklasbec-and-ae-leung).

Comment: Thanks ,
Inside the allSettled, as you can see, I need to check with the index before manually to assign which props.set function and error hanaling to call. How can I do it in a more easy way? (I have also updated it in private chat for detail for what I have written so far) ) @niklasbec